# Working with Multi-Select Drop Downs

Tags: oracle, plsql, multi-select

I have multi-select drop down list where in user can select multiple options, now how can I pass this multi-select options to select query.

**Code**

`select number from table(get_number(('('1','2','3','4','5')','7','8')));`

where `1, 2, 3, 4 and 5` are the multi-select options selected from multiselect dropdown box. Now in get_number function I am passing count_number, role_number and test_id. Count_number represents the multi-select options which user select. So my question is how can I consume multi-select values which user entered in my get_number function, not sure if possible but do I need to define count_number as array in get_number function ?

Comment: Am I missing out to mentioned something in the question or the question itself is not clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not clear what you're trying to achieve. Below is an example of a function that uses arrays as parameter and output.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_number AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  2  /

Type created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_number (p_array tab_number)
  2     RETURN tab_number
  3  IS
  4     l_result tab_number := tab_number();
  5  BEGIN
  6     FOR i IN 1..p_array.count LOOP
  7        /* do something with array */
  8        l_result.extend;
  9        l_result(i) := 2 * p_array(i);
 10     END LOOP;
 11     RETURN l_result;
 12  END;
 13  /

Function created

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_number(tab_number(1,2,3,4,5)));

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           2
           4
           6
           8
          10
```

Comment: Vincent, can you add more comments to the function, especially for lines 8 and 9 in function, I am not able to understand it.

Comment: Also function takes multiple parameters and one of those parameters is an array and so for that parameter if array is not null then I will have to iterate through the loop and do further processing.

Comment: @Rachel: it is not clear what you want to achieve. What is the purpose of your function? In my example I show how you can iterate elements of an array (the FOR loop). Line 8 and 9 would be code for actually doing something with the array. What do you expect the function to return?